# call bash script in script not found, directory is in $PATH

Tags: bash, shell-script, path

I have added a directory to my `PATH` variable to access all my bash scripts. I add the `PATH` globally on the system under `/etc/profile.d/custom.sh` as follow:

```
export PATH=$PATH:/usr/local/bin/helper
```

This works, but when I call them in another script they are not found. Only if I use the full path to there location or I add a `source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh` at the top of an script they run.

All Scripts have a `#!/usr/bin/env bash` at the top.

Is there another way, or have I missed something?

Comment: In a terminal window does `echo "$PATH"` return the expected (new) result?

Comment: yes, i have checked this

Comment: Are you running your code from a cron job?

Comment: Does `ls /usr/local/bin` show `drwxr-xr-x` ? - Same for `/usr/local/bin/helper` ? And the files inside `helper` are all `r-x` for other? -- I'm a little hazy about this, but I believe the "profile" files get read for a login shell, but not for non-interactive shells. Is it possible that your `custom.sh` just isn't being run in the environment in which you expect it to be run?

Answer (score 1):

What might happen is that the default scripts are overwritten by your local custom scripts (you may have modified it locally or just simply forgot to execute default scripts).

Try to add a call to the `custom.sh` script in your user scripts (at the bottom of `~/.bashrc` file):

```
# Running custom.sh
source /etc/profile.d/custom.sh
```

Comment: Hm, i have tried, but it makes no difference

Comment: Adding it to `~/.bashrc` should have done it. For debugging, you might want to have `custom.sh` write a line of text with a timestamp to a file somewhere just so you can prove whether it was run at all. If you just call it from a `.profile` file, everything you source will be unavailable as soon as you go another shell level deeper.